# Connecting to a function which is defined within a separate class

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

I am currently working on a project and I need some assistance. I have made separate classes which include different frames which lead to different pages within the GUI. I am trying to call a function which has been defined within a different class in the project. However, the error which keeps on appearing is that I need to define it within that class. The background of this function is a login system. Once the user has entered the correct details, they are redirected to the another window. Moreover, I am unable to call this function and I don't know how to fix it.

> However, I am also having trouble resizing the actual main GUI2 window. The main window. I have tried many methods but nothing seems to affect the window.

Here is the code:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Century Gothic', size=20)


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (GUI2, Login, PageTwo, LoginSuccessful):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame


            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("GUI2")


class Login(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Please enter your deatils below to login into our voting system",
                         font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Username:",
                         font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.username = Entry(self, width=20)
        self.username.pack()
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Password:",
                         font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.password = Entry(self, show="*", width=20)
        self.password.pack()
        label = tk.Label(self, text="", )
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.text_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Login", height="2", width="30",
                                  command=lambda: self.verify()).pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back", height="2", width="20",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("GUI2"))
        label = tk.Label(self, text="", )

        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button.pack()

        self.users = {}
        with open("StudentVotersFinal.csv", "r") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
            for data in reader:
                self.users[data[0]] = data[1]
                tk.Label(self, text="", ).pack()

    def login(self):
        return self.users.get(self.username.get()) == self.password.get()

    def verify(self):
        verified = self.login()
        if verified:
            print("logged in")

        else:
            msg.showerror("Error message", "You are not eligible to vote in this election")


class LoginSuccessful(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="View Candidates", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("GUI2"))
        button.pack()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation errors in your code. Also, please try to reduce this down to a [mcve].  If the title of the question is accurate, we don't need so much code. All we need is a function in one file and a button in another file.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have reduced the amount of code!

Comment: I would like the if verified statement from the def verify function to give the result of the function in class LoginSuccessful. I have been looking into moving the LoginSuccessful class to do a different python file and using from import function however I would rather connect it through the same python file

Comment: Is `self.controller.show_frame('LoginSuccessful')` what you need?